# i18nのロケールが急に効かなくなった

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, i18n

i18nのロケール設定が突然英語（en）以外効かなくなりました。

何がキッカケかわからないのですが、 
http://sampleurl.com/ja 
としてサイトを開いても日本語表示されず、リンクも全部enへのものしか 
出てこないという状態となっています。

言語ファイルも 
/config/locales 
devise.en.yml devise.ja.yml en.yml ja.yml 
のように用意してあり、現在はen.ymlしか効いていない状況です。

Rubyは2.3でRailsは４．２．３です。Rubyは2.3に最近上げたばかりです。

どこをチェックすべきなのか検討つかないのですが、 
RouteファイルとApplicationControllerは以下のようになっています。 
特に以前動作していた時から変更は加えていないです。

何が問題なのでしょうか？ここをチェックせよという箇所ありますでしょうか？ 
どうかよろしくお願いします

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'


devise_for :users, skip: [:session, :password, :registration], controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }


 # Locale Information
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
   get '/' => 'frontpage#index'
   get 'restaurant/' => 'restaurant#index'
   get 'restaurant/:id' => 'restaurant#show'
   get 'menu/' => 'menu#index'
   get 'menu/:id' => 'menu#show'
   get 'area/' => 'area#index'
   get 'area/:id' => 'area#show'

   resources :reviews

   devise_for :users, skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]

end
```

以下はApplicationControllerです。

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_locale, :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end

  private
  def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)<<:name
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end
```

Comment: 新しく入れた gem が競合しているとかでしょうか？ git log に何か残っていませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。ここ数日に修正したものというと以下の様な感じです。あとはrubyも2.1から2.3に上げました。何かやれるとしたらGemを戻すくらいですかね？
-# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
+gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'

-gem 'puma'
+gem 'puma', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.2'


-gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'
+# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'
+gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'


-#gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
-gem 'mysql2'
+gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'

-# rename
-gem 'rename'
-

Answer (score 1):

すみません。自己レスです。
ApplicationControllerに

```
before_action :set_locale, :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

と書いていたのが問題でした。i18nとdeviseの設定を一緒に書いたことが問題で

```
before_action :set_locale
```

だけに直したら正しく動作しました。